# Getting data from C++ app to LAMP stack

Tags: web-server, c++

I am running Raspian on a Pi. I have a C++ app that is generating some real time data and I would like to make that data available to the web server (on the same Pi). I have a LAMP stack installed.

How would I go about doing such a thing?

I considered simply writing the data to a file and reading it with PHP on the web server. I am not sure that is a good idea since presumably it would be written to the SD card and cause wear.
Should I set up a RAM disk, or is there a more direct way for the data to make its journey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already running a LAMP server, I would write the data to your MySQL database, where it can be read via PHP and displayed.

The MySQL website has [example code](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html) for writing to a MySQL database from C++.

This has one big advantage over a RAM disk or tmpfs it persists the data across restarts, allowing for long term storage and analysis.

Comment: Although I didn't comment about this in my answer, I think persistent storage of whatever form is better idea as well -- don't be scared of writing to the SD card, and don't believe a lot of the hysterics that can be found online about it.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84905/25985

Answer (score 3):

> Should I set up a RAM disk, or is there a more direct way for the data to make its journey?

In this context RAM disks have been superseded by [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs), which is simpler to use and probably already existent on whatever OS you are using, presuming it is a GNU/Linux variant.  To check:

```
mount | grep "^tmpfs"
```

Chances are it includes `/run`, which is world readable, so you can create a writable directory in there with ownership and permissions appropriate to the process. Remember, obviously that doesn't persist across boots, and it will require superuser privileges to *create* the directory regardless of who is then allowed to use it.  Hence, doing it via init is sensible; if the directory isn't used it doesn't matter.

`/tmp` is commonly also a tmpfs filesystem, but it is not on Raspbian.

You can find the maximum size and current usage stats via `df`.  Beware the max size is probably a considerable potential chunk (e.g., on Raspbian it looks like `/run` has ~250 MB), meaning you have plenty of space but if you get out of control, that's RAM you're using.  It sounds like you do not need much.

Answer (score -3):

Your best bet is using MySql , select either XML or JSON for your data format and you will reap the benefits of using these languages as well.